# How to disable menu sounds in The Witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

Is it possible to disable the sounds when clicking on menu items?

Currently I am muting my speakers.

Comment: I don't remember that noise being so annoying. What is bothering you so much to want to completely remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable just that, you'd have to disable SFX or, if that doesn't work, sound entirely.